# Listen for https request, then when received send out another

Tags: node.js, post, https, request

I am trying to build a network of IOTs.

On my node server, I am listening for WAN/LAN HTTPS requests. Upon receipt, I would like it to send out a HTTP request to an independent IOT.  I have gotten a simple example up:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

var a = https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

Can anybody guide on sending out a http POST request to http://192.168.1.137/?pin=ON1, along with the "hello world" in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs for `http.request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) include a sample of how to send a POST request. Here it is modified to send the POST request you ask for.

```
var postData = querystring.stringify({
  'msg' : 'Hello World!'
});

var options = {
  hostname: '192.1681.137',
  port: 80,
  path: '/?pin=ON1',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': postData.length
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

Comment: Trott, thank you so much for writing the program.  I am new to this, so bare with me.  It seems like this is an independent POST request, so I saved this as test.js and ran it using node test.js . it gave me a bunch of errors       node test.js
    /home/pi/test.js:1
 (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var postData = querystrin
                                                                    ^
ReferenceError: querystring is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/test.js:1:78)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26) .....

Comment: i ended up using installing request and altering the example in the doc   https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#tlsssl-protocol

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <http://192.168.1.137/?pin=ON1>
requesting=true    
var https = require('https');
    var fs = require('fs');

    var options = {
      key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
    };

    cout << "hello world">
    var a = https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200);
      res.end("hello world\n");
    }).listen(8000);
```

Comment: Please explain your code; answers with just a code block and no explanation don't follow the guidelines.